# Pandas DataFrame groupby and aggregation per unique value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation

I have following data:

```
value = [["time1", "client1", None, "username1"], ["time2", "client1", "event1", "username1"], ["time3", "client1", None, "username2"], ["time4", "client2", None, "username3"], ["time5", "client2", "event2", "username4"], ["time6", "client3", None, "username5"]]
columns = ["timestamp", "clients", "events", "usernames"]
df = pd.DataFrame(value, columns=columns)
```

The DataFrame looks like:

```
timestamp   clients events  usernames
0   time1   client1 None    username1
1   time2   client1 event1  username1
2   time3   client1 None    username2
3   time4   client2 None    username3
4   time5   client2 event2  username4
5   time6   client3 None    username5
```

I want to realize following calculation:

```
df.groupby("clients").agg(**{
    "total_records": ("timestamp", "size"),
   "unique_users": ("usernames", "nunique"),
   "without_events_records": ("events", lambda x: x.notnull().mean()),
   # "without_events_users":  add calculation without events per unique username
})
```

How can I do the aggregation in the comment row?

Comment: can you elaborate on the comment? Also, shouldn't it just be `1-without_events_records`?

Comment: I want to display the ratio of unique usernames without None in Events column to the total number of unique users on each client. Just like in the previous calculation, I take the ratio of the number of rows without None in the Event column and divide it by the total number of rows in this column.

Comment: in your solution, you are using the total records with non None vs None data in "events" column. But what I need is this calculation PER UNIQUE username in the group of client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you can see some simpler solutions, but I could only construct one.

```
df.groupby(["clients", "usernames"])[["events"]]\
.agg({"events": ("count", "size")})\
.pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.columns.map('_'.join), axis=1))\
.eval("events_count / events_size")\
.reset_index()\
.rename(columns={0: "data"})\
.groupby("clients")\
.agg({"usernames": "count", "data": "sum"})\
.eval("data / usernames")\
.reset_index()\
.rename(columns={0: "without_events_users"})
```

And after that merge it with the previous aggregations on clients column.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df.groupby('clients')['events'].agg(('nunique', 'count')).eval('nunique / count')
```

Output:

```
clients
client1    1.0
client2    1.0
client3    NaN
dtype: float64
```

If you want to divide the number of unique `event`s per `client`, you can use `size` instead of `count`